# What's the regex to solve this problem?

Tags: php, regex

I have an array in PHP with URLs like below:

```
http://example.com/apps/1235554/
http://example.com/apps/apple/
http://example.com/apps/126734
http://example.com/images/a.jpg
http://example.com/images/b.jpg
http://example.com/apps/2331234/
http://example.com/apps/orange/
```

How can I separate out these urls and push them to another array using Regex:

```
http://example.com/apps/1235554/
http://example.com/apps/126734
http://example.com/apps/2331234/
```

Only url with `apps/{number}/` and `apps/{number}` should be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    if (preg_match('~apps/[0-9]~', $url)) echo $url;
}
```

or more restrictive:

```
~apps/[0-9]+(/|$)~
```

to match either slash or the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're not using "/" as the regex separator character to ignore escaping issues, this will do the trick:

```
   "^http://example.com/apps/\d+/?$"
```

Comment: ah, yeah, you need to ensure that there's an end-of-line character at the end. I'll make the edit; thanks.

Comment: Don't forget anchors: `"^http://example.com/apps/\d+/?$"` – otherwise it would match nailxx' example.

Answer (score 0):

`^http://example\.com/apps/\d+\b` — `apps` then slash, then some digits and then word boundary, i.e. not an alphabetic character.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using a negative lookahead to replace all lines that aren't what you want with an empty string:

Replace

```
http://example\.com/(?!apps/[0-9]+).*
```

With

```
''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the URLS with /app/(some digit) and optionally ending with slashes, you can use a loop like this:

```
for ($i = count($urls); $i-->0 ;) {
    if (!preg_match('-/apps/\d+/?$-', $urls[$i])) unset($urls[$i]);
}
```

It cleans your array in-place, without the need to use a temporary one.
I'm assuming that the hostname is not constant, otherwise you can change the regexp with:

```
'-^http://www.example.com/apps/\d+/?$-'
```

I replaced the standard `/` regexp delimiter so that I didn't have to escape the slashes of the URL.