# Regex fix for this? [extension]

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the redundancy, I should've asked this in my previous question here: [What's the regex to solve this problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061407/whats-the-regex-to-solve-this-problem)

This question is an extension:

From the elements in an array below:

```
http://example.com/apps/1235554/
http://example.com/apps/apple/
http://example.com/apps/126734
http://example.com/images/a.jpg
```

I'm separating out `apps/{number}/` and `apps/{number}` using:

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    if (preg_match('~apps/[0-9]+(/|$)~', $url)) echo $url;
}
```

Now, how do I also push `{number}` to another array with the same regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) takes an array as third parameter that will contain the matches. Create a capture group with `()` and the number will then be contained in `$matches[1]`:

```
$numbers = array();

foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('~apps/([0-9]+)~', $url, $matches)) { // note the "( )" in the regex
        echo $url;
        $numbers[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

FYI, `$matches[0]` contains the whole matched pattern as described in the documentation. Of course you can name the array as you like.

Answer (score 0):

If finding the URLs that match is the goal, you could use `preg_grep()` instead:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://example.com/apps/1235554/',
    'http://example.com/apps/apple/',
    'http://example.com/apps/126734',
    'http://example.com/images/a.jpg',
);

$urls = preg_grep('!apps/(\d+)/?$!', $urls);
print_r($urls);
```